# Sitecore Bad Gateway 502 in localhost

Tags: iis-7, sitecore

I have an sitecore installation.. when try to get to the CMS the Sitecore/Login
All the assets such as images, logo, css is not loaded. When I inspect it, it says 502 bad gateway..

Yesterday, my site is worked normally.. There are 2 changes that I do yesterday before going home..

First, I installed the IIS application request route and second, I remove some unused host file in driver/etc/host in windows..

Are this two impacting my sitecore or are there another idea why this happens..

Cheers.. p.s. for your info, I already restart the site and the IIS

Comment: It is highly likely that the Application Request Routing is causing this issue. If you could provide more information on what you are trying to achieve with ARR then someone will be able to provide an answer.

Comment: How about matching the app pool user and permissions to the website folder?

Comment: @Gabbar, that's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue, and I had to install **Server Side Includes** (Add Roles and Features Wizard, Web Server (IIS), Application Development) inside of Add Roles and Features Wizard.

Assuming you are running on Windows 2012 Server

1. Open Server Manager
2. On Welcome to server manager, click item 2 Add roles and features
3. Add Roles and Features Wizard, click next for **Before you Begin** and for **Installation Type**
4. Double check the server you want to install the Role or Feature is correct and click Next
5. Scroll down and find **Web Server (IIS)**, expand it
6. Scroll down and find **Application Development** and expand it
7. Check if **Server Side Includes** and click Next
8. **Features** click Next, then click Install and Close once it finishes

[image]

Can you give a shot and update us?

Thanks,

Vinicius

Comment: Glad to hear that gill23! Cheers, Vinicius